# CSS is different in smartphones/mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, remote-debugging

I am building a website but the responsive CSS is not applied on mobile as I would want it to be. I would like my site to be displayed like so (checked by Chrome dev tools):
[image]

However, when my site is deployed in production, the site's layout is completely different and it differs between Chrome, Safari and SNS browsers.

For Chrome
[image]

For Safari
[image]

For SNS browsers (FB Messenger in this case. Slide is different but the styling is practically the same for all)
[image]

I've had many problems like this where the design I applied to in Chrome Dev Tools is not applied in real life, and everytime these kind of things happen and so far I just use `navigator.useragent` to detect the browser type and apply specific css for each type of browser, but I'm sure this is an overkill.

When this happens, is this usually because chrome dev tools is not accurate, or because my logic is weak? And are there any way to remotely inspect DOM elements on mobile (I'm using OSX) so that I can check what exactly is going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each browser renders differently but I think you might have hidden root or body padding or margin I suggest you play with those either through * {} or body {}

Comment: Thanks man. Is there any way that I can remotely debug mobile front end styling that you know of?
So far I commit and push every little changes, and that's honestly a drag.

Comment: You mean a tool that can show you the layout on different devices and browsers?

Comment: Yes, but specifically something more accurate than Chrome dev tools if any. I find Chrome dev tools to be relatively inaccurate when it comes to styling emulations.

Comment: I honestly use a chrome extension called viewport resizer that helps render more accurately on mobile because i know the pain of doing it in chrome dev tools, i also heard firefox has superior dev tools than chrome but i havent used it yet